# Update Donation Amounts for Monthly Recurring option

Tags: civicontribute

We are in the process of building out a contribution form (not webform) with the One-Time and Monthly option buttons at the top of the donation form.

We are trying to figure out the best option to update the Monthly amounts when someone toggles from One-Time to Monthly.

Has anyone done this? If so, what do you recommend?

Comment: I'm thinking of writing a small extensions that exposes an option on priceset fields "display for: all contribution types / only non-recurring / only recurring", which would then generate a bit of javascript to show/hide the appropriate options.

Comment: With building the form do you mean do it programmatically?

Comment: Yep, well, only the javascript duct-tape to show/hide the appropriate priceset fields depending on whether the user wants to do a recurring or one-time donation.

Answer (score 4):

The extension is available on [CiviCRM's Gitlab](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/pricesetvisibility/tree/master).

It adds a new option that is visible in the administration of the priceset, so that admins can decide when to display a specific priceset field value:

[image: Screencast of an example form]